# laravel query builder, get sum from other table by id

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have 2 table in db, one for user and other for payment

My goal is to have table users with the sum of payment->price by user->id in laravel using query builder

I managed to make a success query in datagrip like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.id
      , users.name
      , users.email
      , users.address, users.is_admin
      , users.created_at
      , sum(payments.price) as total_purchase
FROM users
LEFT 
JOIN  payments
on users.id = payments.user_id
group 
    by payments.user_id, users.name
order by user_id desc;
```

I already try similar query in laravel something like this :

```
public function getUsers(){
    $users = DB::table('users')
            ->select(DB::raw('"SELECT DISTINCT users.id, users.name, users.email, users.address, users.is_admin, users.created_at, sum(payments.price) as total_purchase'))
            ->leftJoin('payments', 'users.id', '=', 'payments.user_id')
            ->groupBy('payments.user_id', 'users.name')
            ->orderBy('user_id', 'desc')
            ->paginate(1);

    return $users;
    // return view('adminUsers', ['users' => $users]);
}
```

but i get error :

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;

How can i do that in laravel?
and i also want to return pagination with it

Comment: try to show full query with toSql() to see if your query is correct

Comment: Thanks for helping. Sorry, i dont get it. What do you means with toSql() ?

Comment: replace paginate(1) with toSql() then debug result with : dd($users) ..

Comment: As debugging steps, it would be good to "uncomplicate" first your query see what causes the issue (ie. remove the groupBy and orderBy) see if you manage to get it to work 

Comment: its show me i have double select statement so i need to remove select statement in raw methods. But the problem still persist, when i return the $users variable its still get me an error

Comment: yeah, nice tips to get :)

Comment: I think I've been using sql for around 7 years. In that time I've never yet had cause to use GROUP BY and SELECT DISTINCT in the same query.

Comment: so how can i make the same approach? I just need add 1 column to user which is the sum of other table value by user id